# Effectively map list of ranges to list of values in file

Tags: awk, sed, files

I have file with values written in ranges, I need to "unmap" them to plain list, how this can be effectively achieved?

Example:

```
141540000,141569999,1
147280000,147289999,0
```

First column is range start value, second value is range end and third value is some data which corresponds to each number in range.

Example result I want to achieve:

```
141540000, 1
141540001, 1
141540002, 1
... 
141569998, 1
141569999, 1
147280000, 0
147280001, 0
...
147289999, 0
```

I suppose the best approach is to use something like sed or awk, but I don`t know how to approach solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{for (i=$1;i<=$2;i++) print i ", " $3}' file
```

For every line we do the for loop and print the number and the last field.

Answer (score 3):

With perl, using the [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlop#Range-Operators) in a list context:

```
perl -F, -ne 'print "$_, $F[2]" for ($F[0]..$F[1])' file
```

or

```
perl -F, -ne 'print map { "$_, $F[2]" } ($F[0]..$F[1])' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS=, read -r start stop data <&3;do
  seq -f "%.0f, $data" "$start" "$stop"
done 3< file
```

The `seq` command will cycle through from start to stop numbers in steps of 1 and print the message along the way.

- the data does not contain any format-special chars like `%` or backslash sequences.